# function object with overloaded type conversion operator crashes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, functor, type-erasure

I'm implementing a type erasure class (I'm studying templates and static polymorphism), that can wrap any callable object (any object that supports the function call syntax).

Reading C++ template complete guide and searching across the web, I came up with this implementation:

```
// erasure.hpp 

class Object
{
friend void swap(Object &, Object&);  // friend declaration
private:
    class Concept
    {
    public:
        virtual ~Concept() = default;
        virtual void Invoke() = 0;
        virtual Concept *Clone() = 0;
    protected:
        Concept() = default;
    };
    template <typename T>
    class Model : public Concept
    {
    public:
        //Model(const T&) : mObject(object) {}
        //Model(T&&) : mObject(move(object)) {}
        template <typename U>                          // forwarding constructor (forwarding (universal) reference)
        Model(U &&object) : mObject(forward<U>(object)) {}    
        void Invoke() override { mObject(); }
        Model *Clone() override;
    private:
        T mObject;
    };
public:
    template <typename T>                              // forwarding constructor (forwarding (universal) reference)
    Object(T &&object) : mConcept(new Model<typename remove_reference<T>::type>(forward<T>(object))) {}  
    Object(const Object &other) : mConcept(other.mConcept->Clone()) {}               // copy constructor
    Object(Object &other) : Object(static_cast<const Object&>(other)) {}             // delegating constructor (inhibits forwarding constructor)
    Object(Object &&other) : mConcept(other.mConcept) { other.mConcept = nullptr; }  // move constructor
    ~Object() {delete mConcept; }                 // destructor
    template <typename T>                         // forwarding assignment operator
    Object &operator=(T&&);
    Object &operator=(const Object&);             // copy assignment operator
    Object &operator=(Object &other) { return *this = static_cast<const Object&>(other); }
    //Object &operator=(Object &other) { return this->operator=(static_cast<const Object&>(other)); }
    Object &operator=(Object&&);                  // move assignment operator
    void operator()();
private:
    Concept *mConcept;
};

template <typename T>
Object::Model<T> *Object::Model<T>::Clone()
{
    return new Model(mObject);
}

template <typename T>
Object &Object::operator=(T &&object)
{
    delete mConcept;  
    mConcept = new Model<remove_reference_t<T>>(forward<T>(object));

    return *this;
}
```

this is pretty classic and straightforward, so I omit the cpp implementation file. It works fine when I construct type erased objects from free functions, functors that overload the function call operator and even lambdas:

```
#include "erasure.hpp"
#include <iostream>

#define PRINT(msg)       std::cout << (msg)
#define PRINTLN(msg)     PRINT(msg) << std::endl;

void FreeFunction()
{
    PRINTLN("in free function");
}

class Functor1
{
public:
    void operator()()
    {
        PRINTLN("in functor overloaded function call operator");
    }
};

class Functor2
{
private:
    typedef void(*PtrToFun)();
public:
    operator PtrToFun()
    {
        PRINTLN("in functor overloaded type conversion operator to function pointer");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Object o1 = &FreeFunction;
    Object o2 = Functor1();
    Object o3 = Functor2();
    Object o4 = []() -> void { PRINTLN("in lambda"); };

    o1();
    o2();
    o4();
    o3();  // error: program crashes

    return 0;
}
```

but when I use a functor (Functor2) that overloads a type conversion operator to function pointer, the program crashes AFTER printing the string inside the operator. It just freezes and crashes (stack overflow?).

Why?

**EDIT**

after comment by  rafix07 I edited the code and now it works:

```
class Functor2
{
private:
    typedef void(*PtrToFun)();
    PtrToFun p = []() { PRINTLN("in functor overloaded type conversion operator to function pointer"); };
public:
    operator PtrToFun()
    {
        return p;
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't have return inside `operator PtrToFun()`, it is UB.

Comment: @rafix07 thanks, I was misusing the conversion operator, if you make this comment an answer I'd be pleased to accept it.

Comment: @Luca Suitable compiler settings would have issued a warning (or error) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Functor2` is just wrapper for pointer to function, so it should take some pointer and return it in conversion operator. Without `return`, you have UB because of calling function on garbage address.

To make `Functor2` take any function with signature `void ()` you could write:

```
class Functor2
{
private:
    typedef void(*PtrToFun)();
    PtrToFun ptr;
public:
    Functor2(PtrToFun p ) : ptr(p) {}

    operator PtrToFun()
    {
        PRINTLN("in functor overloaded type conversion operator to function pointer");
        return ptr;
    }
};

Object o3 = Functor2(&FreeFunction);
o3();
```